# Selecting popular tags without duplicate posts in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, tags

I'm trying to construct a MYSQL query right now that will get popular tags in a certain time range based on how many times they've been used in the date range and with it, the most recent post with the tag.

The problem I'm having is I can't figure out a query that will return the popular tags with its latest post but if that post is already under another tag, return the next most recent post.

This is what I have so far.

$ignore string is basically tags to ignore: "AND $wpdb->terms.name NOT LIKE '%".$ignored."%'"

$limit is a selected limit of tags to return

```
SELECT $wpdb->posts.*, $wpdb->terms.*, COUNT($wpdb->terms.term_id) as count 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->term_taxonomy, $wpdb->terms 
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID=$wpdb->term_relationships.object_id 
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id=$wpdb->terms.term_id".$ignorestring." 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_date < '$now' 
AND post_date > '$datelimit' 
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy='post_tag' 
GROUP BY $wpdb->terms.term_id 
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT $limit
```

I've tried variations of GROUP BYs and JOINS but haven't quite figured it out.